# Css modal scrollable window

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I have a modal window, which after css translate (to center it inside the page) some elements inside of it like button borders become somewhat cut off (at least in chrome): https://jsfiddle.net/r67dsbp8/

Applying some fixes like:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

make whole text blurry in the modal which is even worse.

If I try different markup like so: https://jsfiddle.net/2u5saj4q/

modal content is not scrollable vertically any more. How could I make it scrollable vertically (if more vertical content than fits) in second example?

Answer (score 0):

Set `.mpp-modal-content` height and overflow-y to scroll or auto :

```
.mpp-modal-content {
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teudjs3h/)

Comment: But I cant have fixed height on content, content should auto expand.

Comment: How about set height: fit-content and it's max-height to fixed instead? [like this one](https://jsfiddle.net/5zkq18ba/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont want scroll inside modal window. I can change some modal markup if I can achieve same effect as my first example?